# PHP form dumps entire MySQL database unless neither input variable exists in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that searches a MySQL database using PHP. Currently, when a user inputs a search into one of two fields, the entire contents of the database are displayed. Also, if the user leaves both fields blank, again, the entire contents of the database will be displayed.

However, if the user inputs random information into **both** of the fields, then the results page will be blank.

The assumed usage of this form is that the user can search for an article based on the article's title, the article's author or organization, or the article's title **and** its author or organization by either filling out one or both of the fields.

What I'm trying to figure out is:

Why the results page keeps displaying all of the database contents.

and

How to ensure that the database is actually being queried rather than just being dumped by a coding error.

Code follows below:

search.php:

```
<div class="content">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="searchdb.php">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
            <tr>
              <td width="29%" align="right">Article Title:</td>
              <td width="71%" align="left"><input name="articletitle" type="text" id="articletitle" size="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">Author or Organization:</td>
              <td align="left"><input name="articleorganization" type="text" id="articleorganization" size="50" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

searchdb.php

```
<?php

include('settings.php');
$query = "select * from articles";
$where = array();
if (!empty($_POST['articletitle'])) {
   $where[] = "articletitle LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articletitle'])."%'";
}
    if (!empty($_POST['articleorganization'])) {
       $where[] = "articleorganization LIKE  '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articleorganization'])."%'";
}
    if (!empty($where)) {
        $query .= " WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $where);
        $sql = mysql_query($query);
    } else {
        // No results
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<br/> Article Title: '.$row['articletitle'];
    echo '<br/> Article Organization: '.$row['articleorganization'];
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="entry.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">View Full Entry</a></td>';
    echo '<br/><br/>';
}

?>
```

Comment: It looks like @xbonez has answered your question about what is causing the behavior. Seems like you might actually want to ask how to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I apologize for being vague. I have a form with 2 input fields that I'd like to search the database. Currently, if I enter nothing or random characters into either of the input fields, or if I leave them both blank, the entire contents of the database are dumped. However, if I input random characters into both fields, no results are displayed. Thus, I can't know if the database is actually being queried properly.

Comment: Not a problem, I was just trying to point out how to improve your question so that you'll get the answer you're looking for. It would be a good idea to edit your question so that it will be useful for people who come across it in the future.

Comment: Alright, I've edited the OP. Feel free to make any changes you think would help.

Comment: Is your goal that you have two fields and if both are filled out, a result should be returned only if both match? A result should be returned if either one matches? Perhaps only one field needs to be filled out and if it matches a result should be returned? It seems like your question is stating the problem without stating the goal.

Comment: I see your point there and have edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this, and it should do exactly what you want.

```
$query = "select * from articles";
$where = array();
if (!empty($_POST['articletitle'])) {
   $where[] = "articletitle LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articletitle'])."%'";
}
if (!empty($_POST['articleorganization'])) {
   $where[] = "articleorganization LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articleorganization'])."%'";
}
if (!empty($where)) {
    $query .= " WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $where);
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
} else {
    // No results
}
```

**EDIT**
It appears your form is passing empty values, so instead of checking `isset`, check `!empty`.  I have updated the code above.

Comment: I actually am having the same results as before. Perhaps I've implemented your code improperly. I'm going to update my code above so you can see what I've done.

Comment: Try outputting the `$query` instead of running it.  And see what you have.

Comment: @newlymintedcocoaguy: try the modified version above as it should now work even when getting empty string values from your form.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for hanging in there.

Answer (score 3):

When both are blank, your query states:

`WHERE field LIKE '%%'`

which matches everything.

The same happens when either one is blank, because you are using an `OR` to join the where clauses.

You can prevent this from happening, by checking the inputs aren't blank:

```
<?php
if (!((empty($_POST['field1']) || empty($_POST['field2']))) {
  //run your query
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't allow one field to be filled in and not the other.  I take it that is what the OP wants. @newlymintedcocoaguy: ?

Comment: It wouldn't but it's only a small step from just not putting any empty `LIKE` 's in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Following on the post by @sberry.

```
if (isset($_POST['articletitle']) && $_POST['articletitle'] != "")
```

The variable can be set, but still be an empty string.

The method used by @xbonez is simpler as

`if (!empty($_POST['articletitle']))` is the same as the above example that requires two tests

Have you tried xbonez method?

To be complete, this checks that at least one of the fields has been filled in:

```
if (!empty($_POST['articletitle']) || !empty($_POST['articleorganization'])) {
   $query = "SELECT * from `articles` WHERE ";

   $query .= "`articletitle` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articletitle']) . "%' ";

   $query .= "OR `articleorganization` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articleorganization']) . "%'";

    $sql = mysql_query($query);

} else {
    // No results
}
```

Things that will only be used if one of the fields is filled in like:

```
$query = "SELECT * from `articles` WHERE ";
```

are placed inside the the if() statement, otherwise they are being parsed unneccesarily.

No need to create an array and then convert it into a string. ".=" will concatenate the string fragments into the final query string.

**Matters of personal preference:**
MySql keywords written in full caps, I find it makes the statements easier to read.
There are numerous discussions about it.
Search for "[sql uppercase keywords style](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql%20uppercase%20keywords%20style&submit=search)"

Using backticks around table and fieldnames:
Allows the use of reserved keywords for table or fieldnames (count, case, default, div, index, key, limit, option, order, etc...).
Reduces work for the mysql parser, it doesn't need to check whether there is a reserved word conflict.
Avoids problems if your table or field name becomes a reserved keyword in the future.

Again, numerous discussions. Search for "[mysql backtick](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20backtick)"

**MySQLdocumentation:**
[9.3. Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

[9.2. Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html)
Look for "quoted identifier" on this page.
Also, if you might be migrating to a different database app in the future , you could use double quotes instead of backticks, look for "ANSI_QUOTES".

[9.2.4. Function Name Parsing and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html)
Look for "quoted identifier" on this page.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this example. If I'm reading this right, it enforces both fields being filled in instead of being left blank, correct?

Comment: @newlymintedcocoaguy It checks that one or the other of the fields has been filled out, see my edited answer for further info.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a lot of info. Thanks for that.